# How to join multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am developing a web application using hibernate.

The same application i have created in jsp servlet but now i am using `spring` and `hibernate` but unable to do same thing which i did using `jsp/servlet`

jsp code

```
String sql = "select city from addres_table where id=2";
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
String city = rs.getString("city");
String sql1 = "select name from user_table where city='"+city+"'";
Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(sql1);
while(rs1.next()){
String username = rs.getString("name");
}
}
```

Basically i am fetching `city` from `addres_table` now i am fetching `name` of `users` who are living in that `city` from `User_table`.

Same thing i want to do in hibernate but i am unable to do.

I have fetched `city` from `addres_table` but now how can i fetch `name` from `User_table` using that city.

Here is my hibernate code

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Address> getProfessionById(long id) throws Exception {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Address.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("uid", id));
List results = cr.list();
tx = session.getTransaction();
session.beginTransaction();
tx.commit();
return results;
}
```

Please help me i want to fetch name from User_table using this city

Address class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Address implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="city")
private String city;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

    public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="full_name")
private String fullName;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi this should be easy but before help can you update your mappings too? Like USER and Address class or its hbm file if any..

Comment: Hibernate itself builds a SQLselect statement creating joins and returning the desired output, as specified in your xml configuration

Comment: below is my Address class and User class

Comment: i thought he may be using hbm config file for each class. So i asked. but he is using annotations @VirajNalawade

Comment: @NadeemAhmed  there is no city member in User class..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to map the relation between the two entities, change your classes like this:

**Adress class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profession")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    //Map the users here
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="adress")
    private Set<User> users;
    //getter and setter

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

**User Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="full_name")
    private String fullName;

    //The Adress mapping here
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Adress_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

And then to get the list of the users with a specific city do the following:

```
String hql = "SELECT user.name FROM USER_TABLE user WHERE user.address IN (SELECT address FROM ADDRESS_TABLE address WHERE address.id = :id)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id",2);
List results = query.list();
```

**EDIT:**

Use this query instead:

```
String hql = "from User u INNER JOIN u.address ad where ad.id = :id";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id",2);
List results = query.list();
```

And you will get what you need.

Comment: what is ADRESS_ID in @joincolumn?

Comment: it's the name of the foreign key that will be stored in `USER_TABLE` .

Comment: What's wrong with it? What are you getting as result? What error do you get?

Comment: USER_TABLE is not mapped [SELECT user.name FROM USER_TABLE user WHERE user.address IN (SELECT address FROM ADDRESS_TABLE address WHERE address.id = :id)]

Comment: try it with `user_table` instead ?

Comment: Ok then try the last query in my EDIT.

Comment: user_table is not mapped [from user_table u INNER JOIN u.address ad where ad.id = :id]

Comment: No it's `from User` and not `user_table` we use the class name here and not the table name.